# Reactjs - pass information between siblings by changing parent state

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a react app where I need users to select their phone brand and model. They can select their phone in a sidebar component called "PhoneModel" and I show the picture corresponding to that phone in another component "CaseImg". PhoneModel and CaseImg are siblings.

The way I thought of doing this was keeping this information in the parent's state, changing the state through "PhoneModel" and passing it as props to "CaseImg"

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            phoneBrand: 'Apple',
            phoneName: 'iphone4',
            caseModel: 'bg1'
        };
    },

    handlePhoneSelection: function(phone, name) {
        this.setState({
            phoneBrand: phone,
            phoneName: name
        });
    },

    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <CaseInfo />
                    <CaseImg phoneBrand={this.state.phoneBrand} phoneName={this.state.phoneName} caseModel={this.state.caseModel} />
                    <CustomizeBtns />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <PhoneModel handlePhoneSelection={this.handlePhoneSelection} />
                    <CaseModel />
                    <CustomPicture/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
})

var PhoneModel = React.createClass({

    handlePhoneSelection: function(brand,model) {
        this.props.handlePhoneSelection(brand,model);
    },

    render: function() {

        return (
                <div>
                    <div onClick={this.handlePhoneSelection('apple','4s')}>
                        <imgsrc="/assets/img/apple-4s.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div onClick={this.handlePhoneSelection('apple','7s')}>
                        <imgsrc="/assets/img/apple-7s.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div onClick={this.handlePhoneSelection('apple','7splus')}>
                        <imgsrc="/assets/img/apple-7splus.png" />
                    </div>
                </div>  
        );
        }
})
```

I've tried a lot of different solutions I found on related questions but keep getting the same error:

```
setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

ps: this app is simple, I don't want to use Flux or Redux.

EDIT: fixed the typo mentioned, which was not present in my original code

Comment: I'm sure it's a typo in your question, but you're missing the closing parenthesis on your callbacks, `this.handlePhoneSelection('apple','4s'`, which look to be invoked immediately by the way, which would cause an infinite render cycle.

Comment: You're doing it correctly but like @lux pointed out you have typos that are most likely causing the errors.

Comment: Actually it was a typo I made when I copied the code here. It's was correct in the original code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onClick points to the result of `this.handlePhoneSelection('apple','4s')` rather than the `handlePhoneSelection` function:

`<div onClick={this.handlePhoneSelection('apple','4s')}>`

So inside the render method, `this.handlePhoneSelection('apple','4s')` is triggered in the process of rendering and tries to update the state.

And you need to do this instead:

`<div onClick={() => this.handlePhoneSelection('apple','4s')}>`

Comment: I tried that as well but then I get this error: `Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type boolean`...maybe I should bind the (this) on the parent component?

Comment: This error message does not make sense... `() => this.handlePhoneSelection('apple','4s')` can never be of type boolean?

Comment: Yeah, I don't get it as well. I guess the handler function inside the child component is returning false for some reason

Comment: Do you have some other onClick listener?

Comment: That was it. I had another onClick on a separate div that was causing the trouble. When I removed that and used your syntax it worked. Thanks!